# How to fetch dockerhub registry image layers in Java?

Tags: java, docker, docker-registry, amazon-ecr

I attempted using Google's Jib package and it doesn't appear to work.

```java
        FailoverHttpClient httpClient = new FailoverHttpClient(true, false,
                ignored -> {});
        var client = RegistryClient.factory(EventHandlers.NONE, "registry.hub.docker.com", "ubuntu", httpClient)
                .newRegistryClient();
        var manifest = client.pullManifest("latest");
        var template = manifest.getManifest();
```

Throws a 404 exception.   If I try using `library/ubuntu` for the image name, it throws a 401 exception.

Is there possibly another way to do this?

Comment: The DNS for Docker Hub's registry API is `registry-1.docker.io`. Many clients automatically map `docker.io` over to this, but I don't know about Jib.

Answer (score 1):

1. Get token:

   ```
   curl 'https://auth.docker.io/token? 
   service=registry.docker.io&scope=repository:library/ubuntu:pull'
   ```

   resp:

   ```
   {
       "token": "tokentokentokentokentokentoken",
       "expires_in": 300,
       "issued_at": "2023-02-27T11:41:47.155402344Z"
   }
   ```
2. Get manifest, [https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/${tag](https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/$%7Btag) or image digest}

   ```
   curl 'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/manifests/sha256:c985bc3f77946b8e92c9a3648c6f31751a7dd972e06604785e47303f4ad47c4c' --header 'Accept: application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json' --header 'Authorization: Bearer tokentokentokentokentokentoken'
   ```

   resp:

   ```
   {
       "schemaVersion": 2,
       "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.manifest.v1+json",
       "config": {
           "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.config.v1+json",
           "size": 2299,
           "digest": "sha256:58db3edaf2be6e80f628796355b1bdeaf8bea1692b402f48b7e7b8d1ff100b02"
       },
       "layers": [
           {
               "mediaType": "application/vnd.oci.image.layer.v1.tar+gzip",
               "size": 29528717,
               "digest": "sha256:677076032cca0a2362d25cf3660072e738d1b96fe860409a33ce901d695d7ee8"
           }
       ]
   }
   ```
3. Get layer, [https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/blobs/${config](https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/blobs/$%7Bconfig) or layer digest}

   ```
   curl 'https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/ubuntu/blobs/sha256:58db3edaf2be6e80f628796355b1bdeaf8bea1692b402f48b7e7b8d1ff100b02' --header 'Authorization: Bearer tokentokentokentokentokentoken'
   ```

   resp:

   ```
   stream(save to file)
   ```